# How can I query a webform in all instances at once to export a file?

Tags: 7, webforms, drush, importing-exporting, multi-sites

We recently had a security breach and those making the decision opted to remove the capability of end users to create the file upload component.

What I am hoping to do is two-fold:

1.) Use drush sql-query to iterate through all our databases and return all webforms using the file upload component. Optimally this output would need to be sent to a .txt file or something similar so that we know which webforms to address and which sites were using it.

I am hoping to use sql-query with a SELECT statement to look at the webform_component table to get this data so that we can take action.

I know how to drush simple things to a text file, on each database directly (drush @cms.name_of_database site-alias >all.txt), and I know how to use drush sql-query to UPDATE but I do not know how to iterate through each of our databases and then output the results of the query into a single .txt file.

2.) Use Drush to disable the file component (Configuration > Content Authoring > Webform Settings) to uncheck the file component.

We have about 300 sites so we are really hoping we can avoid having to manually configure this across all 300 databases/sites.

Note: I am not trying to export/import content types, I am trying to query our databases via drush and output the results into a .csv or other file type. My second issues is that I need to iterate that script across all 300 databases we have and output the results to either a single file or a file for each db

Comment: That's a task for the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module as outlined in some of the answers in the other question. Create Webform on one instance, export to feature module, enable/import feature module on all other instances, and finally export all instances config. Use Features to sync particular config and/or bundles across all instances during development and in the end you still export every instance's config on their own. Drush at hand.

Comment: @leymannx - This doesn't really answer my question. I am not trying to export/import content types, I am trying to query our databases via drush and output the results into a .csv or other file type. My second issues is that I need to iterate that script across all 300 databases we have and output the results to either a single file or a file for each db.

Comment: Ah, there are two questions! I thought you want to sync some config across all 300 instances. Okay, now that I've read it again this sounds like a **custom Drush command** from a custom module enabled on all sites. And wasn't it for Drush 8 that there is the `@sites` alias to simply iterate through all sites? Try it out with `drush @sites status` for example. Otherwise this would be a task for a simple Shell script to iterate through all directories inside the sites directory.

Comment: Please try to have your post contain **only one question**. And for the second question create a new post instead.

Comment: Have you considered [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) to create those CSV files?

Comment: This should be a simple bash script - `drush sa` to list the aliases, refine if needed, then loop over and run a drush command for each to gather data

Comment: `@sites` was only removed in Drush 9. It should still be in Drush 7 as well.

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to figure out how to append the results to a single file with the following using "@"sites: 

drush @sites sql-query "SELECT nid FROM webform_component WHERE type = 'file'" >> /path/to/directory/file-components.tsv -y -v;

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Nice! Add that as an answer below and accept it. 